# Import new photos from iPhone into Windows XP

Tags: iphone, photos, windows

I'm on Windows XP and wish to plug in my iPhone and have all new photos imported into a folder on the hard disk. New photos I'm simply defining as those that it hasn't imported before.

Simple, eh?

The default Microsoft Image Aquisition tool seems to read all photos rather than just new ones.

Any ideas out there?

If I could see the iPhone photos as a drive letter I would write my own little application in Java, but this doesn't appear possible.

Edit: Found this similar question: [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4945/how-do-i-download-photos-from-my-iphone?rq=1)

Comment: Doesn't it show up as a drive with a folder 'DCIM' on Windows File Explorer? Apple Mobile USB Device Driver installed OK, right?

Comment: No it doesnt show as a drive letter. I just get an entry in My Computer called "David's iPhone" or whatever the device is called. If I click on this I get a listing of all the photos on the phone. I do have an entry in device manager called "Apple Mobile Device USB Driver" which seems to be working OK. I can sync with iTunes fine over USB.

Comment: so...can't you Copy and Paste those into a folder in My Pictures or wherever?

Comment: Yes I can do this manually, but I would like an automated solution i.e. just connect the iPhone and the new pictures "magically" get transferred onto the PC's hard disk in a predetermined location. I've got a script for this for my digital camera, which maps as a drive letter, but no joy for the iPhone.

Comment: and you know you can use "Get pictures from camera" https://discussions.apple.com/message/6352553?messageID=6352553 (not automated but easy to use and built-in [if this works for you, tell me and I'll post it as an answer])

Answer (score 0):

You can use dropbox to do this. Although dropbox is mainly a tool to administer files in the cloud, it recently obtained the option to automatically read and store in the cloud new photos from an attached camera/sd card/iPhone when it is connected to the PC. The data is stored in a special directory on your hard disk which is mirrored in the cloud.  When deciding to store photos in dropbox's cloud you get some GB (6?) of storage for free. Dropbox itself is free and you get the benefit of the cloud.

Answer (score -1):

If you are willing to use third party programs you can try [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) or [iDevice Manager](http://www.iphoneexplorer.net)

They both claim that they are compatible with Windows XP and can mount your iPhone as external storage.

Once it is mounted as external storage you can write your Java applet to copy/move your images from your "external storage"-iPhone to your local drive destination.

Answer (score -2):

I use GoodSync to keep two folders in 'sync'. So it will work if iphone/ipad can be visible as exernal usb drive in windows 7/xp.

Comment: As is mentioned in the question, iPhone photos do not work as a drive (no drive letter otherwise @davidfrancis would not be asking.

Answer (score -3):

Use phone disk. It mounts your iPhone or iPod .... and can you give example of your applet code....
Thanks
Raji

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you please provide a bit more details to make your answer stand out, especially a link to the application's web site and your reasoning why this alternative is better (or equally good) than the ones mentioned in the other answers?